# Pyexcel at elementary level

Tags: indexing, pyexcel

I have a excel sheet as follows: [[x1, x2, x3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] and want to add two columns, say y1 and y2, filled with 0. Then, I want to replace e.g. y1 zeros by x1 values if x1 values are >= 2. I do not find in Pyexcel tutorial how to do this operation. Can someone please help me on this? Thanks in advance,
Abdul

I tried to find a solution in the tutorial, but with no success. Also find an indexing solution based on a single value, e.g. 12; not a condition like >= 2